# Difference between str.clear() and str = ""

Tags: c++, string, stdstring, std

I have a C++ `std::string str` that I've set to some string, and now want to reset so it can be used again. Is there a difference between calling `str.clear()` vs `str = ""`?

EDIT. To clarify: I'm reusing str by appending a char array buffer to it: `str.append(buf)`

Comment: They are two ways of achieving the same result. One is using a class method and the second using the overloaded operator `=`. Choose the one which cleary expresses your intent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no effective difference.  Depending on the implementation, using `clear()` may be faster than assigning to a char pointer to zero.  Even if this were not the case, though, prefer the method that more clearly expresses your intent.  If you want to clear the string, use `clear()`.  If you want to assign an empty string, use `= ""`.

Though I will note, you said, "so I can use it again."  Use it again for what?  If you are just assigning it to something else, there's no need to clear it beforehand.

Comment: There is a 'semantic difference' but no 'effective difference' (please excuse the nit-picking)

Comment: Nit-picking is always appropriate.  Editing.

Comment: Updated question re: reuse.

Comment: Last para is well said. Just because C++ gives you some features doesn't mean that you have to use all of them.